# SQL Query - using COUNT

Tags: sql

I have a database structure like this:

```
Table - lodges
LodgeID (PK)
Lodge
etc

Table - scores
ScoreID (PK)
Score
CategoryID
LodgeID (FK)
```

I'm trying to return results in the form:

LodgeID, Lodge, Category, Number of Scores in that Category, Average Score in that Category

So for example, if I had:

**lodges**

```
LodgeID, Lodge
1, Lodge One
2, Lodge Two
```

**scores**

```
ScoreID, Score, CategoryID, LodgeID
1, 3, 101, 1
2, 5, 101, 1
3, 7, 101, 1
4, 10, 102, 2
5, 20, 102, 2
6, 30, 102, 2
7, 40, 102, 2
```

I'd like to return:

```
1, Lodge One, 3, 5
2, Lodge Two, 4, 25
```

I've been trying things like:

```
SELECT        COUNT(ScoreID) as scoreCount, AVG(Score) as AverageScore, Lodge 
FROM          scores_temp 
INNER JOIN    lodges_temp ON scores_temp.LodgeID = lodges_temp.LodgeID
```

SELECT lodges_temp.LodgeID, Lodge, COUNT(ScoreID) as scoreCount, AVG(Score) as AverageScore FROM `lodges_temp` INNER JOIN `scores_temp` ON lodges_temp.LodgeID = scores_temp.LodgeID

Without any success. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should look into `GROUP BY`.

Comment: did you add Group By Lodge at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT        COUNT(ScoreID) as scoreCount, AVG(Score) as AverageScore, Lodge 
FROM          scores_temp 
INNER JOIN    lodges_temp ON scores_temp.LodgeID = lodges_temp.LodgeID
GROUP BY Lodge
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `group by` clause:

```
SELECT     COUNT(ScoreID) as scoreCount, AVG(Score) as AverageScore, Lodge 
FROM       scores
INNER JOIN lodges ON scores.LodgeID = lodges.LodgeID
GROUP BY   lodge
```

Comment: Thank you! I always forget about Group By!